# How do I do ASCII to EBCDIC translation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding, jruby, ebcdic

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 on Mac OS X.

How do I convert ASCII to EBCDIC encoding, to communicate with legacy system.
Would I have to use to jruby?

Comment: The first suggestion would be to use `iconv`, except it seems that iconv doesn't support EBCDIC; This has been an issue for years. :-/

Comment: @Mark why is the question hurting ur head?

Comment: The juxtaposition of technologies is just too radical. I was kidding of course.

Comment: EBCDIC? Now there's an acronym I've not heard in a long, long time.

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade but that doesn't necessarily solve the problem.

There are multiple flavors of EBCDIC (THANK YOU IBM!) so you'll need to identify the subset your mainframe uses.

One thing I learned to do when programming on the mainframe, oh so many years ago, was to call some of the mainframe sysops, and pick their brains. They deal with conversion from other codesets into EBCDIC all day long, and probably have a tool that can do it on the fly.

An alternative would be to see if they have something that can parse JSON or YAML. Convert your text to UTF-8, send it to the mainframe, let its translator convert from UTF-8 to EBCDIC.

Comment: Amen to "(THANK YOU IBM!)". Without IBM's work and experience developing EBCDIC, we might have been stuck with its contemporary 7-bit ASCII for who knows how long. And the experience helped with their contributions to the Unicode Consortium from the beginning of the organization. We'd likely be in far worse shape today. But you're right; it's possibly necessary to identify the EBCDIC CCSID of the relevant mainframe users and a good thing to do even if not necessary. (Though it might not be a "mainframe", the idea is still relevant.) And if not, UTF-8 is a good intermediary.

Comment: In python it is as easy as "123".decode("UTF-8").encode("IBM500")  or whatever flavour you need, usually 037, 500 International is popular because of it being widely accepted for DB2 unicode support. So why is this not in Encoding.aliases for ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Ruby [iconv library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) (for Ruby versions before 2.0) or the [iconv gem](http://ruby-doc.com/gems/docs/i/iconv-1.0.4/) (for Ruby 2+) specifying EBCDIC-US as the codeset:

```
irb(main):001:0> require('iconv')
=> true
irb(main):002:0> x=Iconv.new('EBCDIC-US','ASCII')
=> #<Iconv:0x7fb4274d88d8>
irb(main):003:0> x.iconv("foo")
=> "\206\226\226"
```

Comment: I seem to be getting "Iconv::InvalidEncoding: invalid encoding ("ascii", "EBCDIC-US")" . On OSX

Comment: Can you find out what version of iconv you are using?

Comment: i am using 1.11. Looks like ineed to upgrade

Comment: Well, it may be that EBCDIC support is only in Linux' glibc.