# Ruby How convert HEX in EBCDIC-US

Tags: ruby, converters, ebcdic

How is possible to convert an HEX string to a EBCDIC-US string in ruby?
Is there any library? I looked for and I didn't find anything.
The only other way that I have in mind is to build a conversion table from hex to ebcdic but are 255 chars.
Any suggestion or idea?
I using Mavericks and I tried iconv
but with

```
Encoding.name_list
```

I don't have EBCDIC-US

Comment: Did you see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718324/how-do-i-do-ascii-to-ebcdic-translation-in-ruby)?

Comment: You might not need `EBCDIC-US` if `ISO-8859-1` works for you. Also, ensure that any conversion is **only** applied to text and not to any possible embedded BCD "packed" values or binary values.

Comment: You could try the IBM037-encoding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913407/ebcdic-to-ascii-in-ruby