# EBCDIC to ASCII in RUBY

Tags: ruby, ebcdic

I have a EBCDIC file that was generated from a Mainframe and will need to convert it to ASCII for data processing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's better to [provide a simple example and expected result](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do ASCII to EBCDIC translation in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718324/how-do-i-do-ascii-to-ebcdic-translation-in-ruby)

Comment: This question is indeed a duplicate of that; the answers were a bit outdated (depending on which version you're using) but I have updated [the appropriate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4718545/1735262).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard 2.0.0-p247 :002 > x=Iconv.new('EBCDIC-US','ASCII')
Iconv::InvalidEncoding: invalid encoding ("EBCDIC-US", "ASCII")
 from (irb):2:in `initialize'

Comment: Weird... it works for me. Did you install the gem, or are you just using the library? It appears that maybe 2.0.0 still has the library.

Comment: It seems to work for me on Ruby 2.2.0 (though I don't have any EBCDIC files to really test it on). It might be worthwhile to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Ruby 2.3 the EBCDIC-encoding is available][1]:

> Encoding
>
> new Encoding::IBM037 (alias ebcdic-cp-us; dummy)

So this should work:

```
src = 'out_26877296.tst'
content = File.read(src, encoding: 'IBM037:ASCII')
```